# How use LIKE Query with 2 tables?

Tags: jquery, mysql

I have a problem for use LIKE query with 2 tables. This is my code :

```
select a.id_employee,a.name_employee,b.time,b.desc 
from login_user a,tbl_log b where b.id_log LIKE '%LOG_LOGIN-%' and 
b.desc LIKE 'a.name_employee%'`
```

but still don't show a result.

Answer (score 1):

Column names aren't substituted inside strings. You're looking for the actual string `a.name_employee` in `b.desc`. Use `CONCAT()` to concatenate strings so you can combine the column name with the literal `%`.

Also, you should learn to use ANSI JOIN to specify the relationship between tables.

```
select a.id_employee,a.name_employee,b.time,b.desc 
from login_user a
join tbl_log b ON b.desc LIKE CONCAT(a.name_employee, '%')
where b.id_log LIKE '%LOG_LOGIN-%'
```